# Getting incorrect timings while calculating difference between 2 datetime

Tags: c#

I am trying to calculate time difference between 2 datetime but getting incorrect time.

I have 2 datetime like below :

```
 DateTime end = new DateTime(2018, 04, 13, 12, 17, 39, 067);
 DateTime start = new DateTime(2018, 04, 13, 12, 17, 38, 893);
 string s = string.Format("{0:%m} : {0:%s}", (end - start)); // 0:0
```

I should get 1 seconds but getting `0 minutes and 0 seconds`.

Moreover i also want to have 2 digits output like below :

```
00:01
```

but still it yields 0 : 0 only :

```
string s = string.Format("{00:%m} : {00:%s}", (end - start)); // 0:0
```

I will appreciate any help :)

[image]

Comment: Isn't the difference only 0.174seconds - so expressed as minutes & seconds would be 0:0  - check the result of _(end - start).ToString()_

Comment: @PaulF [Yep, you're right](http://rextester.com/CAXK90307)

Comment: Why do you expect there to be a 1 second difference between your 2 date times? There is only 174 milliseconds difference, did you expect that to be rounded up?

Comment: new DateTime(2018, 04, 13, 12, 17, 39, **000**) perhaps if you need second precision you should drop the other information.

Comment: Let's wait 1 nano Sec... Ok that's definitivly a whole second, right?

Comment: @DragandDrop - I'm guessing OP didn't actually create a new DateTime with that accuracy - but obtained it from clicking on the Now labels. So what needs to be done is set millisonds to zero before the calculation.

Comment: @PaulF I have this timing saved in my database which have milliseconds so i think i miss this rounding part which leads to 1 second difference.Though i dont think this question is that bad to get 5 downvotes.Is it?

Comment: @User: I think the downvotes (not mine) are because the answer was so obvious - try the following _"var diff = end.AddMilliseconds(-end.Millisecond) - start.AddMilliseconds(-start.Millisecond);"_ to resolve the problem.

Comment: @PaulF Yeah but i missed it hence got punishment in the form of 4 downvotes from SO users :)

Comment: Well that the issue with "simple error" when you just miss Something. here you claim that they were one solid second. But just by looking at the number it was weird. But don't take it as a punishment. sometime we ask dumb question but the ruberducking of writing question on SO, should have filtered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been commented on - the problem is due to the millisecond accuracy. You can subtract the millisecond by adding the negative of the milliseconds:

```
DateTime end = new DateTime(2018, 04, 13, 12, 17, 39, 067);
DateTime start = new DateTime(2018, 04, 13, 12, 17, 38, 893);
var diff = end.AddMilliseconds(-end.Millisecond) - start.AddMilliseconds(-start.Millisecond);
string s = string.Format("{0:mm} : {0:ss}", diff);
Console.WriteLine (s); // 00:01
```

Note if the end value were 38seconds & 967milliseconds for example - so within the same actual second - then 00:00 would be displayed.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and for your valuable time but how do i add leading zeros?

Comment: ss and mm are typo? because it return 11  http://rextester.com/WNSPP27979

Comment: @DragandDrop: %s & %m would print 0:1, %ss & %mm print 00:01 as OP wants.

Comment: if diff is more than 9 sec display becom fun.

Comment: @DragandDrop:But i can have difference in minutes and seconds too.

Comment: @PaulF Now the output is 00:10

Comment: Are you sure you haven't changed something else? Go to the link Drag and Drop gave above & delete the % signs & run it

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's 0:0. The website you're testing against is rounding **up** to the nearest second.

If you want to emulate it, you will have to round up too:

```
DateTime end = new DateTime(2018, 04, 13, 12, 17, 39, 067);
DateTime start = new DateTime(2018, 04, 13, 12, 17, 38, 893);
var difference = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Ceiling((end - start).TotalMilliseconds / 1000.0));
string s = string.Format("{0:mm}:{0:ss}", difference);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

[Fiddle](http://rextester.com/ZPUBHO6768)

Comment: Looking at the picture displayed - I am guessing OP got the precise times by clicking on the Now labels - but is only showing time to second accuracy. In which case if the user clicked each label within the same second - then both boxes would show the same time - so the output should be 00:00. Your code would show 00:01.

Comment: Though now i am getting correct timings i.e 1 seconds but i am not getting leading zeros.I am still getting 0 : 1

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and for your valuable time :)

Comment: It is the m & s that needed changing to mm & ss, not the 0 changing to 00. The 0 is the parameter index for the format string.

Comment: @User Sorry, I got distracted by Netflix :) Try now.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help :)